# Executing JavaScript code in the Visual Studio Code terminal and not output

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, terminal

I want to execute JavaScript code in the Visual Studio Code terminal.  I installed the [Code Runner](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=formulahendry.code-runner) extension, but it is executing code in "Output" where I am not able to enter run-time input values.

To execute in "terminal", I have to type "node pgm.js". Is there a way by which I can directly execute JavaScript files in the Visual Studio Code terminal by using shortcut <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd>?

Answer (score 0):

Go to settings and configure the Code Runner extension to output to the terminal.

Also, you need Node.js for it. If that doesn't work, you don't need code runner. Use Node.js from a normal terminal.

From the top, go to menu *View* → *Terminal* to open the normal terminal. Then run the command `node filename.js` to execute it.

Comment: how to use node from normal terminal. Please tell me a bit in detail  , I am a newbie.

Comment: From the top go to View > Terminal. To open the normal terminal. Then run the command `node filename.js` to execute it.